# Arrange files according to their sizes while considering their units too in swift4

Tags: ios, compare, swift4

I have some files stored in cache directory .I want to fetch the size of those files and arrange them in ascending order.

For fetching the size of file I have done the following code:-

```
func transformedValue(value:Any)->Any{
        var convertedValue:Double = (value as AnyObject).doubleValue
        var multiplyFactor = 0
        let tokens = ["bytes","KB","MB","GB","TB","PB","EB", "ZB","YB"]
        while convertedValue>1024 {
            convertedValue = convertedValue/1024
            multiplyFactor = multiplyFactor+1
        }
        return String.init(format:"%4.2f%@",convertedValue,tokens[multiplyFactor])
    }
```

For Sorting,Following code is done:-

```
sortedFileDetails = allFileDetails.sorted(by: { $0.size < $1.size })
                print("sortedFileDetails by size",sortedFileDetails)
```

Issue-
After sorting ,I am getting values arranged by numbers without considering the units i.e if two files,A and B with sizes 2 mb and 250 kb ,it shows 250 greater than 2 which is wrong.

I want to sort it correctly.Kindly give some suggestions to sort it correctly while considering the units too.Any kind of help or suggestion would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep `size` always in `bytes`. The `transformedValue()` stuff, is only for UI, used it in UI. Could be a `humanReadableSize` computed property.

Answer (score 0):

Your data should maintain the original raw size as a number. Sorting should be done on that number. You should only create a string from the number for display purposes.

You should have a look at the `ByteCountFormatter` class for converting the size into a string. No need to write your own code for that.